# No class names in Uml diagram generated by pycharm

Tags: uml, pycharm

I was generating uml by using pycharm, but when i tried to do it, user classes has no title, even though when refactoring it is showing actual class names.

[image: pycharm uml diagram]

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

open the class folder as the project.

[image: pycharm class diagram]

Comment: Hello, could you please explain what you mean by opening the class folder as the project?

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the case for you, but what worked for me was renaming the file I was trying to create a diagram from to one that does not include a whitespace character

*(Pycharm version: 2017.3.2)*

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me as I had number at the beginning of the file - like `1_file.py`. Renaming to `_1_file.py` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the most up to date version of the software PyCharm 2017.2.3. I have found a solution by creating a new file using PyCharm, then copying and pasting my code in to it.
The problem occurs with files that are created using Python Idle 3.6.1 Shell.